# Creating a definition text from 3 string arguments

Tags: c#, strings

Here is my code to create a definition text from 3 arguments. Is there any way to make it work with better performance and look nicer?

```
 private const string IllegalCharacters = "\\" + "\"" + "'#,.[]{}" + " ";

 public static string CreateDefText(string mainId, string     secondaryId,    string extraText)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(mainId);
        if (sb.Length > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondaryId))
        {
            sb.Append("_");
        }
        sb.Append(secondaryId);
        sb.Append(extraText);
        if (sb.Length > 0 && (char.IsNumber(sb[0]) || '+'.Equals(sb[0]) || '-'.Equals(sb[0])))
        {
            sb.Insert(0, "N");
        }
        foreach (var illegalChar in IllegalCharacters)
        {
            sb.Replace(illegalChar.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), string.Empty);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code Style

**Logic section**

Use blank lines to separate your code into logical sections

Instead of:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(mainId);
if (sb.Length > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondaryId))
{
   sb.Append("_");
}
sb.Append(secondaryId);
sb.Append(extraText);
```

You can write:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();   // section of object creation

sb.Append(mainId); // section of appending mainID

// section of checking for mainID and secondaryID
if (sb.Length > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondaryId))
{
   sb.Append("_");
}

sb.Append(secondaryId);
sb.Append(extraText);
```

The same for the rest part.

**Long condition in if statement**

Don't use long condition in if statement. It's not readable.

Instead of:

```
if (sb.Length > 0 && (char.IsNumber(sb[0]) || '+'.Equals(sb[0]) || '-'.Equals(sb[0])))
```

You can use:

```
isNum = char.IsNumber(sb[0]);
isPlus = sb[0].Equals('+');
isMinus = sb[0].Equals('-');

if (sb.Length > 0 && (isNum || isPlus || isMinus) 
{
   sb.Insert(0, "N");
}
```

We can move deeply and I want to get rid of this long if statement:

```
if (sb.Length > 0) 
{
   isNum = char.IsNumber(sb[0]);
   isPlus = sb[0].Equals('+');
   isMinus = sb[0].Equals('-');

   if (isNum || isPlus || isMinus) 
   {
      sb.Insert(0, "N");
   }
}
```

I still don't like this if construction, I'll extract this code into separate method. Before this I'll create an array of legal symbols

```
if (sb.Length > 0) 
{
   isNum = char.IsNumber(sb[0]);
   isLegalSymb = isLegalSymb(sb[0]);

   if (isNum || isLegalSymb) 
   {
    sb.Insert(0, "N");
   }
}
```

Separate method for checking if character is legal.

```
private static bool isLegalSymb(char symb) {
   string[] legalSymb = { "+", "-" };

   for (int i = 0; i < legalSymb.Length; i++) {
     if (symb.Equals(legalSymb[i])) {
       return true;
     }
   }

   return false;
}
```

**Comments**

*Your code is not always obvious and other developers may don't understand anything without a context of this code.*

In such situations you can provide more comments to make our life more easy.

It relates to your code:

```
foreach(var illegalChar in IllegalCharacters) {
  sb.Replace(illegalChar.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), string.Empty);
}
```

I'm also confused with:

```
private const string IllegalCharacters = "\\" + "\"" + "'#,.[]{}" + " ";
```

I'll again extract this code into separate method:

```
replaceAllBannedCharacters(sb);
```

Separate method for replacing all banned symbols:

```
private static void replaceAllBannedCharacters(StringBuilder sb) {
  string[] bannedSymb = { "#", "'", ".", "[", "]", "{", "}", "," };

  for (int i = 0; i < bannedSymb.Length; i++) {
    sb.Replace(bannedSymb[i], string.Empty);
  }
}
```

## Naming

**mainId** can be replaced with **firstID**

**secondaryId** can be replaced with **secondID**

Comment: I have only one obligation. The name of the method isLegalSymb() should be changed to something like IsIllegalStartSymbol(), because we are checking the illegal symbols in this case.

Comment: @Endery, firstly I used this method name, but it seems very difficult to read a lot of 'lll'', that's why I've changed it to another name.

Comment: I should confess that I have never thought like that. Interesting point.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be rather unclear, with a surprising amount of logic in relatively few lines.

Take for instance `IllegalCharacters`: I kind of see the point of constructing it like that, but at the same time it feels clumsy and counter-intuitive. I'd be more inclined to construct it like this:

```
private static readonly char[] IllegalCharacters = { '\\', '"', '\'', '#', ',', '.', '[', ']', '{', '}', ' ' };
```

I'd split up `CreateDefText` into smaller methods; certainly the last part deserves its own method:

```
private static string Clean(StringBuilder sb)
{
    foreach (var illegalChar in IllegalCharacters)
    {
        sb.Replace(illegalChar.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), string.Empty);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Same for the test of the first character:

```
private static bool IsN(char startChar)
{
    return char.IsNumber(startChar) || '+'.Equals(startChar) || '-'.Equals(startChar);
}
```

So what's left are the shenanigans with the `StringBuilder`. Which seem over-complicated and make it hard to determine the logic. Here's my solution:

```
public static string CreateDefText(string mainId, string secondaryId, string extraText)
{
    var items = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainId))
    {
        items.Add(mainId);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondaryId))
    {
        items.Add(secondaryId);
    }

    var result = string.Empty;
    if (items.Any())
    {
        result = string.Join("_", items);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && IsN(result[0]))
    {
        result = "N" + result;
    }

    result += extraText;

    return Clean(new StringBuilder(result));
}
```

Not that I'm too happy with this. Naming is still bad, and I'd prefer to move the various parts into their own methods, so it is clearer what happens.

Comment: Join() on an empty list gives `string.Empty' so we can just use `result = string.Join("_", items);`

Comment: I liked the suggestion to split up the method into smaller methods, I will definitely do it. But the answer from @martin-shil is covering more issues, so I will accept that one. Please do not be upset.

Comment: @AlanT Ah yes, true.